# How do I embed Keycloak OIDC in my Web App

Tags: authentication, go, keycloak, openid-connect, basic-authentication

I really hope someone out there can help me :)
I am working on a Backend Server for an Uni-Project. Its basically done but now a friend of mine told me, that I can use our Login-Data to implement a Login which would be pretty awesome. He set up a keycloak instance for me where I configured a client for my Server. Keycloak configured a RedirectURI to http://localhost:8080/callback, which I also wanted to use in my project.

Since ChatGPT Produced nothing but garbage I figured I'd ask here.

Anyway here's the Router function

```golang
func Network_Router() { 
        r := mux.NewRouter() r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/assets"))))
        r.PathPrefix("/evaluation/data/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/evaluation/data/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../hugo/this/data"))))
    
        // Add Routing
        r.HandleFunc("/", Network_Homepage_Handler)
        r.HandleFunc("/createEvaluation", Network_CreateEvaluation_Handler)
        r.HandleFunc("/evaluation/{subdomain}", Network_EvaluationSite_Handler)
        r.HandleFunc("/api/evaldata", API_returnData)
    
        r.HandleFunc("/callback", CallbackHandler)
    
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
    }
```

I basically want to protect all routes so they require you to be logged in. I got to that point via Middleware, where I could authenticate but always ended up in a redirect loop after that.

For anyone interested here's the function that brought me there

```golang
package main

import (
"log"
"net/http"
"context"
"fmt"

    "github.com/coreos/go-oidc"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"

)

var (
clientID     = "data"
clientSecret = "data"
redirectURI  = "http://localhost:8080/callback"
keycloakIssuer = "data"

    store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("test"))

) // I used the right data

func main() {
Network_Router()
}

func Network_Router() {
r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/assets"))))
    r.PathPrefix("/evaluation/data/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/evaluation/data/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../hugo/this/data"))))
    
    // Add Routing
    r.HandleFunc("/", AuthMiddleware(Network_Homepage_Handler))
    r.HandleFunc("/createEvaluation", AuthMiddleware(Network_CreateEvaluation_Handler))
    r.HandleFunc("/evaluation/{subdomain}", AuthMiddleware(Network_EvaluationSite_Handler))
    r.HandleFunc("/api/evaldata", AuthMiddleware(API_returnData))
    r.HandleFunc("/login", KeycloakLoginHandler)
    
    r.HandleFunc("/callback", CallbackHandler)
    
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

}

func CallbackHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r \*http.Request) {
// Retrieve the session
session, err := store.Get(r, "session")
if err != nil {
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}

    // Get the original requested URL from the session or query parameter
    originalURL, ok := session.Values["originalURL"].(string)
    if !ok {
        originalURL = "/"
    }
    
    // Clear the session value
    delete(session.Values, "originalURL")
    session.Save(r, w)
    
    state := r.URL.Query().Get("state")
    code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")
    
    log.Printf("CallbackHandler: state=%s, code=%s", state, code)
    
    // Perform token exchange and other necessary validation here
    
    // Redirect to the original requested location after successful authentication
    http.Redirect(w, r, originalURL, http.StatusSeeOther)

}

func AuthMiddleware(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r \*http.Request) {
// Retrieve the session
session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
if err != nil {
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}

        idToken, err := validateToken(r)
        if err != nil {
            // User is not authenticated
            log.Printf("User not authenticated: %v", err)
    
            // Store the original requested URL in the session
            session.Values["originalURL"] = r.URL.Path
            session.Save(r, w)
    
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
            return
        }
    
        // User is authenticated, print some information for debugging
        log.Printf("Debug bug bug, %v", idToken)
    
        // Proceed to the next handler
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }

}

func validateToken(r \*http.Request) (\*oidc.IDToken, error) {
ctx := context.Background()
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, keycloakIssuer)
if err != nil {
return nil, err
}

    config := oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     clientID,
        ClientSecret: clientSecret,
        RedirectURL:  redirectURI,
        Endpoint:     provider.Endpoint(),
        Scopes:       []string{oidc.ScopeOpenID, "profile", "email"},
    }
    
    // Exchange the authorization code for a token
    token, err := config.Exchange(ctx, r.URL.Query().Get("code"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    // Verify the ID token
    rawIDToken, ok := token.Extra("id_token").(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("missing id_token in OAuth2 token response")
    }
    
    idToken, err := provider.Verifier(&oidc.Config{ClientID: clientID}).Verify(ctx, rawIDToken)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    log.Printf("validateToken: code=%s, clientID=%s, clientSecret=%s", r.URL.Query().Get("code"), clientID, clientSecret)
    
    return idToken, nil

}

func KeycloakLoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r \*http.Request) {
// Redirect the user to the Keycloak login page
ctx := context.Background()
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, keycloakIssuer)
if err != nil {
log.Printf("Error creating OIDC provider: %v", err)
http.Error(w, "Unable to create OIDC provider", http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}

    config := oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     clientID,
        ClientSecret: clientSecret,
        RedirectURL:  redirectURI,
        Endpoint:     provider.Endpoint(),
        Scopes:       []string{oidc.ScopeOpenID, "profile", "email"},
    }
    
    state, err := randomString(10)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Sucks to be you")
    }
    authCodeURL := config.AuthCodeURL(state)
    
    log.Printf("Redirecting to Keycloak login page: %s", authCodeURL)
    http.Redirect(w, r, authCodeURL, http.StatusSeeOther)

}\
```

with most of it being GPT and frustation.

All used Methods are implemented and work properly except the ones handling the OICD stuff`

Comment: "Since ChatGPT Produced nothing but garbage"—yep, that's what it does. It spews out characters that kind of sort of maybe make sense together. Occasionally, they even form correct statements. But very often you get trash. ChatGPT is _not intelligent_. It has no idea what it's "saying".